# Tomcat DataSourceRealm Only works once

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to implement DatasourceRealm Security to a test jsp webapp.

This is my web.xml configuration for the security constraints

```
<security-role>
    <description>application administrator</description>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/administration/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>    

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Admin Login</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

and my context.xml

```
<Context path="/TipTrip0.22">
 <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" logAbandoned="true"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/triptip" password="jijikos" 
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" username="spirus"/>

 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" debug="99"
     dataSourceName="jdbc/triptip" localDataSource="true"
     userTable="Users" userNameCol="Emailaddress" userCredCol="Password"
     userRoleTable="Users" roleNameCol="Type"/>
</Context>
```

Tomcats pop up verification works, although just once!After succesfully entering credentials the first time, it allows direct access to the url even after restarting the app!
I also cannot successfully login as a user,which worked fine before implementing the security constraint, getting the following stacktrace:

```
Nov 16, 2014 1:05:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LogInServlet] in context with path [/TipTrip0.22] threw   exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at data.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:44)
at data.UserDB.selectUser(UserDB.java:111)
at appUsers.LogInServlet.doPost(LogInServlet.java:35)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Using : jdk-7u51 Windows7 Tomcat 7.0.52 Netbeans 7.4 Oracle XE11g2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the name declared inside Resource element was inconsistent 
when called from ConnectionPool class

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/spirus");
```

all it needed was replace spirus with tiptrip as declared inside context.xml